# Is there any way to save a single object using Entity Framework Core if there are already altered objects it is tracking?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Using Entity Framework Core, I am batching up objects to be saved.  During this batching process, I want to explicitly create a new object and I don't want the other objects to be created yet.

```
public void Generate()
{
    DbContext context = GetDbContext();
    context.Add(new MyUser());
    context.Add(new MyUser());
    DoSomethingElse(context);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public void DoSomethingElse(DbContext context)
{
    var something = new Something();
    // add new object and save only this new object
}
```

Is there any way to save `something` without saving the two `User` objects?

I've thought about using a new instance of DbContext, would that cost much to instantiate?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being marked down? can you give some feedback?

Comment: Is it possible to add the other object before the previous two? EF follows UoW pattern. You would need to separate the actions.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ok i'll look into seperating the actions.

Comment: Is `DoSomethingElse` dependent on the previous objects?

Comment: No.  `DoSomethingElse` is seperate to `MyUser`. i've simplified my solution to make an easier example

Comment: I am not sure what actually you want to achieve, but you can create second instance of database context and use that one for separate actions.

Comment: Sometimes when the question is more or less "When I do this it hurts" then the answer is "don't do it". Split the job into multiple things that doesn't share a single context, or uses units of work, don't try to solve after the fact that things are now combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DoSomethingElse` is not dependent on the previous actions then consider separating then into distinct units of work.

For example

```
public void Generate() {
    DbContext context = GetDbContext();
    DoSomething(context);
    DoSomethingElse(context);
}

public void DoSomething(DbContext context) {
    var something = new Something();

    // add new object and save only this new object

    context.SaveChanges();
}

public void DoSomethingElse(DbContext context) {
    context.Add(new MyUser());
    context.Add(new MyUser());    
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```